# Windows couldn't connect to system event notification service

Tags: windows-7, laptop

This error just started appearing out of the blue. Never had this problem before.

I tried all sorts of fixes on the internet but none of them worked.

Btw. I am running Win7 on my laptop.

Comment: if you already tried things, can you tell us what the status is of the "System Event Notification Services" in services? What is the status of the 2 "COM+" services in services?  If either of these services do not start, what is the error they show?

Comment: Hi! Restarted both of the 2 "com+" services and SystemENS. They show no error.

Comment: When does it happen? Can you get into the event viewer ever?

Comment: How much free space do you have on your system partition? There's an old bug that will cause the service to fail when there's not enough space.